# Website with suggestions of itinerary

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks

I'm planning to go to south America for 1-2 month, I and wanted to know if there is website, offering (maybe) based on user's feedback road to follow and/or others informations.

I would use a such website as "inspiration", to give me idea...

I searched here with the tag "Website"(https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), also on reddit but didn't find anything (maybe I'm searching wrong).

Thanks

Comment: This would be a good time to visit your local travel agency.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. There are hundreds of travel guidebooks for South America; just pick one that has some sample itineraries and go from there. For such an expansive area as all of South America, there is no single right way to do the trip, so itinerary critiques from strangers on the Internet won't provide much value anyway. There are also organized tour companies that will assemble a few destinations (though probably not all of South America) that you could model a trip on.